# How to find $A = M^{A}_{B}$in linear transformation $F = \mathbb{P_{2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{2}} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

How to find $A = M^{A}_{B}$ in linear transformation $F = \mathbb{P_{2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{2}} $, where $ F(p(t)) = \begin{pmatrix} p(0) \\ P(1) \end{pmatrix},$
$ A = \{1,t,t^{2}\},$
$B=\left \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix} \right \}$?

Comment: Is there something in particular you're struggling with, or don't understand?

Comment: I don't know way of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$F(1)=\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}=1\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}+1\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}$$ $$F(t)=\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}=0\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}+1\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\quad F(t^2)=\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}=0\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}+1\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}$$ Transposing coordinates,$$M_B^A=\begin{pmatrix}{1}&{0}&{0}\\{1}&{1}&{1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I would be grateful if you could answer me a one more question related to this problem. How can I now calculate $w = F(v)$, once direct and once with relation $c_{B}(w) = Ac_{A}(v)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean to compute directly $F(a+bt+ct^2)=\ldots$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, when $v = a + bt + ct^{2}$.

Comment: Look at my new post. Better that in the comment's section.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want the matrix for the transformation? In general, to find the matrix for a linear transformation, you look at what it does to the basis vectors and make that as the columns, in terms of the basis for the codomain.

Let $p_1(t) = 1$, $p_2(t) = t$, and $p_3(t) = t^2$.

Since $F(p_1(t)) = [1, 1]^T = \boldsymbol{1} [1, 0]^T + \boldsymbol{1} [0, 1]^T$, the first column of $A$ is $[1, 1]^T$. (I bolded the two $1$s for emphasis, since that's what's causing it to be $[1,1]^T$.) Since $F(p_2(t)) = [0,1]^T = \boldsymbol{0} [1,0]^T + \boldsymbol{1} [0,1]^T$, the second column of $A$ is $[0,1]^T$. Similarly for the third column.

Answer (score 1):

Anoher way, $$F(a+bt+ct^2)=\begin{pmatrix}{a}\\{a+b+c}\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}$$ $$=a\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}+(a+b+c)\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{1}\end{pmatrix}.$$  Then, in coordinates in the basis $A$ and $B$, $$F\begin{pmatrix}{a}\\{b}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}{a}\\{a+b+c}\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}{1}&{0}&{0}\\{1}&{1}&{1}\end{pmatrix}}_{M_B^ A}\begin{pmatrix}{a}\\{b}\\ c\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful!